How to refresh token using apps script oauth2 library?
I wanted to know if it is possible to auto refresh token if one has expired and not have to authorize apps script application every time.


    return OAuth2.createService('myService')
      .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth')
      .setTokenUrl('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token')
      .setClientId(credentials.web.client_id)
      .setClientSecret(credentials.web.client_secret)
      .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
      .setCache(CacheService.getUserCache())
      .setLock(LockService.getUserLock())
      //.setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage')
      .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive')
      ;

I thought this would auto store and refresh token but when I keep a time driven trigger it doesn't run because of error with authentication.

Can you share why just not use the ScriptApp.get0AuthToken()? I am thinking that the library has no way to bypass the Re-authorization hence not suitable for time driven event triggers since as the 0auth library states this part of its workflow. This information is not persisted to any data store, so you'll need to create this object each time you want to use it.


Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79158611 It is possible that Google revokes the refresh token and that is the main cause of your issues. 2. You may need to setParam offline to true


@TheMaster Thanks I think that worked for me
